# Mixing ObjC and C++ with C++ template classes in more than one source

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, ios, templates

I'm just thinking of porting some old C++ sources held in my archive to iOS thus supplying a ObjC GUI, using wrappers for some C++ stuff and leave the important data working stuff within the C++ code. So, the problem is that the old sources come from Win32 MFC thus using CString class for strings and I want to replace that with Joe O'Leary's CStdString which is a C++ template class that will do it just fine ... but:

I have to use the string class definition along with a big bunch of different C++ sources and so each of them will include the CStdString template on their own. Normally I would write a wrapper for the whole string class, but better if I needn't.

Will I have a problem with instantiation of strings in the different sources? Could it make a problem to pass a templated string from one source to another? In fact I don't know if the compiler generates the code for a template only once or multiple times having the fact that the same instantiation type is used for the template.

Can you fill some light into this?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with CString, as long as you stay with std::string or some other multi-platform string implementation for C++ you are not going to face any issues ( even boost works on iOS ).

I've been integrating C++/Obj-C for about two years now so you can be sure that keeping model classes in C++ ( even with heavily templated code ), is not a problem. I would advice you to do what you could do best with Obj-C in Obj-C though... ( avoiding being a hammer developer :) )

Good luck!

Comment: Hello Mr.Gando, that sounds really good :-) So that means std::string which is the base class of CStdString can indeed be included in different sources within the same project and the code for that is build only once? - Your last advice: ok, in the meantime I'm quite familiar with Obj-C but that shouldn't mean that I'm willing to rewrite a big amount of working C++ code ;-)

Comment: I agree, portability is also a good argument. You could just try to drop CString in your xcode project and see what happens. If it has dependencies with windows stuff things could go wrong. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Ok, I take your uncommented point on multi-filed template includes as a YES ;-)
My tests are not with the whole bunch of cpp sources, that will take more time. Up to now I can say that I can drop in the typedef'd CString having no compiler errors, no leaks (Analyzer & Instruments) and I get nice results like this
reverted: )-: .thgir ot tfel morf gnirts lamron a si siht

Answer (score 1):

MFC and `CString` may only work properly on Windows OS so they aren't good candidates to be putting in any kind of library that will be potentially used by a platform other than windows.

I'm not familiar with Joe O'Leary's `CStdString` classes but I'd recommend using `std::string` as much as possible and `char*` with `"extern C"` exports and wrapping functions for use outside of C++ land as the c-style string is more easily compatible with other languages that may need to call into your C++ library.

As far as templates all the variations are generated at compile time and then the correct implementation is chosen at run time as far as I know.  However your problem will most likely be in translation from one kind of string to another which may require you to create some middle layer or wrapper to marshal from string type of one language to another.

Comment: Well, Joe's CStdString is in fact a derived class from std::string. I've used it many times and today I dld'd the latest version of it (it is dated 2005 and the last one I used is 4 years older) and made a test with a Obj-C wrapper class via opaque pointer. Everything went well. So the string transport Obj-C <=> C++ is not a bit of a problem. The main aspect using this class was that I can make a typedef to CString on CStdString and supply it to most of the existing code because beneath one other class I have to replace it is the only important MFC type used in there.

Comment: Deriving from STL strings i.e. `: public std::string` is a bad idea since `std::basic_string` destructor is not `virtual`. If any members are added in his implementation his derived object will not be properly destroyed. `std::string` is not intended nor properly implemented to be a base class for inheritance.

Comment: Thanks, good point! Anyway, bad thing - good thing: CStdString has no own members. It's a straightforward wrapper for one/two byte instantiations of std::basic_string with the convenience of most features that MFC CString offers and a wide usability. I used it on Linux more than 10 years ago and on Win32 where I couldn't use MFC. Joe's work on it started 1998 with help of ~50 people within 7 years of development. I think they've managed the poorly side effects being in the template.